# "import json" works well in IDLE, but fails in Windows 7 cmd

Tags: python, json, windows, cmd

Simple python script:

```
import json
```

works well in IDLE, but gives me this output in CMD

```
C:\Users\TheJ\Desktop>test4.py
qIQNlQSLi
eOEKiVEYj
aZADnMCZq
bZUTkLYNg
uCNDeHSBj
kOIXdKBFh
dXJVlGZVm
gZAGiLQZx
vCJAsACFl
qKWGtIDCj
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TheJ\Desktop\test4.py", line 3, in <module>
    import json
  File "C:\Users\TheJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 106, in <module>
from .decoder import JSONDecoder, JSONDecodeError
  File "C:\Users\TheJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 5, in <module>
from json import scanner
  File "C:\Users\TheJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\scanner.py", line 11, in <module>
NUMBER_RE = re.compile(
AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'compile'
```

OS is Windows 7 HP SP1 x64,
system locale is ru_RU, codepage is 866

the output of sys.version and sys.path:

IDLE:

```
3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)]
['C:\\Users\\TheJ\\Desktop',
'C:\\Users\\TheJ\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Lib\\idlelib', 
'C:\\Users\\TheJ\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip', 
'C:\\Users\\TheJ\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Users\\TheJ\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\TheJ\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32', 
'C:\\Users\\TheJ\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages']
```

CMD:

```
C:\Users\TheJ\Desktop>test4.py
3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)]
['C:\\Users\\TheJ\\Desktop', 
'C:\\Users\\TheJ\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip', 
'C:\\Users\\TheJ\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Users\\TheJ\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\TheJ\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32', 
'C:\\Users\\TheJ\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages']
```

No idea is it a 32/64bit problem, or Unicode/Windows1251, or some path problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess is you have a file named `re.py` in current directory, which hides the built-in `re` module. The error says _"module 're' has no attribute 'compile'"_, so I suggest you should debug why. Try with this `import re; print(re)`, to see what `re` is.

Comment: What's the output of `python -c "import re; print(re.__file__)"`?

Comment: OMG. I'm so oblivious. Yes, I had re.py on my desktop and had no idea that it might interfere.

Comment: Thank you, guys.
How do I like an answer, BTW?

Comment: There is no answer at the moment, but only comments. You could wait a bit until one of the comment authors post an answer to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it, or you could just post an answer on your own and even accept this then.